# Joint probability distributions with continuous random variables

Tags: statistics

Let $X, Y$ have the joint pdf $f(x, y)= 2, \quad 0 < y < x < 1$

I'm trying to calculate the marginal probability density functions, but I don't know which intervals I'm supposed to use. The source I'm learning from will interchange the following

$f_X(x) = \int_0^x$

$f_Y(y) = \int_y^1$

vs.

$f_X(x) = \int_x^1$

$f_Y(y) = \int_0^y$

I know they're just variables, but if the question asks me for $f_{(X|Y)}(x | Y = y)$, then I'm going to have different answers am I not?

Also, would it make a difference if it was $0 \leq y \leq x \leq 1$?

Comment: Draw the line $y=x$. Our joint density function "lives"  in the part of the standard $1\times 1$ square that is above the line $y=x$, so in the triangle with corners $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(0,1)$. If the condition were instead $1\le y\le x\lt 1$, the joint density would live on the other half of the square. The work would be similar with some small changes of detail. As for the conditional density $f_{X\mid Y}(x\mid Y=y)$, hard to justify the formula quickly in a comment, but it is $\frac{f(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}$, and you will have evaluated the denominator earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to get the marginal $f_X(x)$ you integrate $\int f(x,y)\mathop{dy}$ over all of $\mathbb{R}$. However, you have to consider the region where your joint density is nonzero.

For your particular joint density, $f(x,y)$ is zero when $y\ge x$ or $y \le 0$, so this would reduce to only integrating over $y \in (0,x)$, i.e. $\int_0^x$. [Alternatively, you can think of this as integrating only over the region where your joint density is defined/nonzero.] Similarly, $f_Y(y) = \int_y^1 f(x,y) \mathop{dx}$.

I suspect the second pair of integrals in your textbook is for a different density defined on a different region: $0 < x < y < 1$.

And no, there is no difference between $\le$ and $<$ if you have a density. This may change when your cdf is not continuous, but I don't think you need to worry about this yet.